# How to swap between map fragment and list fragment in android while updating both fragments with AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps, android-maps-v2

My strategy for doing this was very simple while using a MapView, but I am now transitioning over to Android Maps v2 and have to use a MapFragment. My scenario involves getting a list of events, and then I need to Geodecode these in the background to get their latitude and longitude to calculate distance from user and also to place onto the map. I have an actionbar button that allows the user to switch between the list and map fragment, but my issue is how do I keep both fragments in memory and avoid their lifecycle so that I can continually add markers to the map fragment while updating the list adapter in the list fragment?

Currently I replace the FrameLayout by FragmentTransaction.replace with each Fragment, but this causes the other one to get destroyed, whereas I simply want it to be hidden (before I would simply set the MapView visibility to View.GONE).

**EDIT**

My code ended up being:

```
@Override
    public void swapFragments() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        if (listFragment.isVisible()) {
            transaction.hide(listFragment);
            if (mapFragment.isAdded()) {
                transaction.show(mapFragment);
            } else {
                transaction.add(R.id.root, mapFragment);
            }
        } else {
            transaction.hide(mapFragment);
            transaction.show(listFragment);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working on something similar. What I do is create both fragments in the `onCreate()` portion of my main `FragmentActivity` --- then based on the onclick action, I show and hide the appropriate fragments. I supplement this by adding to the back stack before I commit my hiding of the listFragment so that when a user presses back, they'll get the list again and not the previous activity.

However, at the moment, I'm having trouble with getting the GoogleMap to not be null in my MapFragment for some reason.

I solved this issue -- you can find a similar answer here [MapFragment Error - CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904277/mapfragment-error-cameraupdatefactory-is-not-initialized/14910955#14910955)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Using show/hide was the correct thing to do.

Comment: Also, the GoogleMap can't be retrieved till onActivityCreated() in the MapFragment has occurred it seems, so I use a callback to do my work after that part. If you need I can show code.

Comment: yea,  my code doesn't quite reflect that but I noticed that as well. another warning on using my code for anyone is that rotation doesn't work as well, but this shouldn't be too difficult a fix via saving the instance states.