# MapFragment Error - CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized

Tags: android, android-fragments

Trying to create a ListFragment --> MapFragment activity for the phone. MapFragment code follows:

```
public class MapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if(getMap() != null){
            Log.v(TAG, "Map ready for use!");
            mMap = getMap();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return root;
    }

    public void animateTo(double lat, double lng){
            Log.d(TAG, "mMap animating...");
            LatLng mCurrentPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mCurrentPosition, 16));
    }
}
```

But I get the following error ---

```
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913): java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.at.a(Unknown Source)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.J(Unknown Source)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Unknown Source)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.test.app.MapFragment.animateTo(MapFragment.java:113)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.test.app.MapActivity.onListItemClick(MapActivity.java:270)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.test.app.SimpleListFragment.onListItemClick(SimpleListFragment.java:65)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-15 17:12:53.232: E/AndroidRuntime(6913):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I thought calling the MapInitializer would fix it, but doesn't seem to do the trick. Does this have something to do with the timing of calling the `getMap()` method?

Comment: Are you sure `mMap` isn't null at this point? The call to `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom` will be made first, so you won't see a NPE on `mMap` - but that would explain seeing this error.

Comment: In my main activity, I call `MapFragment mFragment = new MapFragment()` which I thought would mean mMap would not be empty. Maybe this is an incorrect assumption? After calling that, I use a `FragmentTransaction` to try to replace my a `FrameLayout` with an id of `content_frame` but it's been giving me the NPE.

Comment: Well, you've got a log call in there - does "Map ready for use!" appear in your logs anywhere before the exception?

Comment: If you check the Fragment lifecycle, `onActivityCreated` is called _after_ the calling activities `onCreate` returns. So if you're creating your fragment in the `onCreate` method of your main activity, be aware that anything performed in your `onActivityCreated` method won't run until after the calling activities `onCreate` returns - so if you're calling `animateTo` within the activities `onCreate` method, then `mMap` will be null.

Comment: Tried putting the `MapInitializer` and the `getMap()` in the `onAttach()` state but I still get a NPE...

Comment: Where is `animateTo` being called from?

Comment: I have a ListFragment with a method `OnListItemClick` in an interface  that my main Activity implements. The `animateTo()` is being called when a user taps on one of the items in the ListFragment.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24601/discussion-between-adamsp-and-codedawg82)

Comment: alright, let's do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed up the implementation here. Used a new layout that had both fragment classes of the listFragment and the MapFragment within a FrameLayout. Then found these by their FragmentIds and then used show/hide in conjunction with adding to the back stack to make the map/list show to the user. I'm not sure what overhead this incurs using two sets of fragments being shown/hidden, but seems to work quite nicely on a Nexus4 :)

Code available here:
https://github.com/codedawg82/AndroidFragments/

Comment: The Above link was broken